# How to format text with hover overlay image

Tags: html, css, hover

I have the following code with the goal to display a name without hovering centered in the shape, then after hovering having a bio of 5 lines all centered with minimal spacing between line breaks.

The problem in my code currently is formatting the front-side to be all centered and have the same big font as the after-hover, and even more notably wrong- the info on the back is coming off the end of the shape. Not centered.

```
<html>

<div id="box">
  John Doe

  <div id="overlay">
    <span id="plus">Title:<br>DOB:<br>Hometown:<br>Info4:<br>Info5:</span>
  </div>

</div>

<style>

body {
  background: -1;
}

#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* NEW */
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 0 66px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease;

  /* NEW */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#box:hover #overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

#plus {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  font-size: 24px;
}


</style>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an answer to all of your questions, but to get the font styles to be the same, add the font styling that you have for #plus to the #box selector instead. You will have to change the color for the box selector to black and for #plus you can leave what you currently have for the color.